# Windows form app saving to .txt method

Tags: c#

Hi I'm attempting a self project to write a shopping cart program that allows users to add, remove, drop(singular removal), delete(remove all), save (like a receipt), update(change added item data) and I'm having an issue with the saving currently.
I looked around on Stack overflow and found something that seems to almost work but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly... Method below

```
public void Save(string fileName)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\barry\Desktop\GG\pewpew\receipt.txt", contents);
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly is supposed to replace "contents" I guess a description of my going about this will help understand.
File structure is a WFA with two added classes for functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents is the text you want to save to the file.

So:

```
public void Save(string fileName, contents)
{
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, contents);
}
```

Would give you a text file containing the text from the contents parameter. The file would be the name the was given for the filename parameter.

To get all of the items from the listbox, you could use:

```
var items = "";

foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
   items += item.ToString();
   items += "\n";
}

Save(@"C:\my-file.txt", items);
```

Comment: ohhhh, what if I want to save something that a user inputs? I'm trying to get the contents of my listbox to save to the file and I don't seem to be able to call lbItems (name of my listbox)

Comment: Do you want all entries or only the selected entry?

Comment: all of the items (it's supposed to be like a receipt :D)

Comment: Updated my answer to include getting the selected items from the listbox.

Comment: You should wrap the WriteAllText call in a try...catch block. Any call involving the file system can be challenging! ;-)

Comment: Yeah I've been trying to implement this and ended up breaking my project pretty much haha. Just going to confirm my thought process to see if this would be along the right lines... 
1. create method that takes filename and content parameter
2. filename = file  and contents = listbox
3. trycatch around sys.io.file.writealltezt(filename, contents)

Comment: You may need to format the text a lot more, as a list of selected items is not really acceptable as a receipt to a customer.
As a first step, get the code to write to a text file. Once you have this, then you can concentrate on the formatting of the text.

Comment: Yeah I'll focus on that after i'm finished crying over my broken code :D thank you for the help! <3

Comment: Heey sorry to bother about this, I've been trying to call my listbox however I keep getting the error that tells me "lbItems doesn't exist in this context"

Comment: Is the name correct and what line is causing the error message?

Comment: the name is definately correct method is this
public void Save()
        {
            var items = "";

            foreach (var item in lbItems)
            {
                items += item.ToString();
                items += "\n";
            }
            Save(@"C:\Users\barry\Desktop\receipt.txt", items);

        }

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the foreach() line and check the value of lbItems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94720/discussion-between-luke-and-karl-gjertsen).

Comment: thanks for helping me out with the save method it works correctly and saves stuff great now :D I was wondering if sometime if you dont have more prying matters to attend to I could pay you something for your time to help me out with other parts of my app? ^^

Answer (score 2):

contents is the string you want to write on the txt file

Answer (score 2):

`contents` is the data you want to write to the file i.e. the receipt contents. You will need to build the receipt up as a string and pass this in to `WriteAllText`

Rough example:

```
public void Save(string fileName)
{
     var content = new StringBuilder();
     foreach(var cartItem in shoppingCart)
     {
          content.AppendFormat("Item: {0}{1}", cartItem.Name, Environment.NewLine);
     }

     System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\barry\Desktop\GG\pewpew\receipt.txt", contents.ToString());
}
```